# Need help on Java, JPA, Thymeleaf and Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm new on this site and new in coding. I am struggling to link the two by referencing Competition to User, and retrieve the data from the database (I'm using Mysql Workbench). It's connected but I can't make it work on my localhost (gave me the Whitelabel Error Page). It could be my code or template that needs correcting.

```
@Entity
public class Competition {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "competition", targetEntity = User.class)
    private List<User> users;

    public Competition() {}

    public Competition(Integer id, String title, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id_User;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Competition competition;

    public User() {}

    public User(Integer id_User, String name, String role) {
        this.id_User = id_User;
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Integer getId_User() {
        return id_User;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public Competition getCompetition() {
        return competition;
    }
}
```

```
public class CompetitionService {

    @Autowired
    CompetitionRepository competitionRepository;

    public List<Competition> getAllCompetitions() {
        List<Competition> competitions = new ArrayList<>();
        competitionRepository.findAll().forEach(competitions :: add);
        return competitions;
    }
}
```

```
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(users :: add);
        return users;
    }
}
```

```
public interface CompetitionRepository extends CrudRepository<Competition, Integer> {
    public List<Competition> getAllCompetitions();
}​
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{}​
```

```
@Controller
public class CompetitionController {

    @Autowired
    private CompetitionService competitionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String competitionListing(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("competitions", competitionService.getAllCompetitions());
        return "list";
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>List of Competitions</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Short Competitions</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Competition Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="competition : ${competitions}">
        <td>
            <a th:href="@{'/competition/' + ${competition.id}}"
               th:text="${competition.title}">Competition Title</a>
        </td>
        <td th:text="${competition.description}">Competition Description</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Find error message, stacktrace?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting on my localhost:                                   
 Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Sep 10 20:10:05 BST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact error you get ? Are there problems with finding the path /list or you get another error. 
As i can see your services are not annotated with `@Service` and repositories also (`@Repository`) which can cause a problem ( i am not pretty sure). Please tell us whats the exact error ? 
When you run your app, look at the console of your IDE for stack trace.

Cheers!

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Sep 10 20:10:05 BST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available .   Thanks!

Comment: Hey, can you show me the structure of the project ? Maybe there is a problem with the routing. What is the name of your view ? is it **list.html** ?
Cheers

Comment: Hi Tobieski,  Thanks for your help, and yes, it is just the @Service that is missing.. It's all working fine now... Thank you